# A line not plotted using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Why isn't the line `y = 6x - 9` being plotted?  I have the proper `xmin`, `xmax`, `ymin`, and `ymax` values.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=2.25in, height=2.75in, axis on top,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4,xmax=4, domain=-4:4,
    ymin=-4,ymax=16,
    restrict y to domain=-4:16,
    xtick={\empty}, ytick={\empty},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[samples=501, domain=-4:4] {x^2};

%\addplot[samples=2, latex-latex, domain={5/6+0.01}:{4-0.01}] {6*x - 9};
\addplot[samples=2, latex-latex, domain={5/6}:4] {6*x - 9};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is due to the numerical precision. You are restricting the domain to -4 from below and the result of 5/6*6-9 comes out as almost -4 and gets discarded hence it actually draws a single point... If you relax the constraint to even -4.00001 you will get the plot back

Comment: @percusse you nailed it (I should have realized this in my investigations); please consider answering.

Comment: @percusse  `(5/6)*6 - 9 = -4`.  You say that this computation "comes out as almost -4."  Are you saying that the estimates used in handling the fraction `5/6` makes the computation actually less than -4 and since I have `ymin=-4`, the point is ignored?

Comment: @Adelyn Yes (5/6*6) comes out as `5.000020400000000` then if you subtract an integer it is `-4.000020400000000` which is slightly smaller than `-4`.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the number of points and all is well.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=2.25in, height=2.75in, axis on top,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-4,xmax=4, domain=-4:4,
    ymin=-4,ymax=16,
    restrict y to domain=-4:16,
    xtick={\empty}, ytick={\empty},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[samples=501, domain=-4:4] {x^2};

%\addplot[samples=2, latex-latex, domain={5/6+0.01}:{4-0.01}] {6*x - 9};
\addplot[samples=100, latex-latex, domain={5/6}:4] {6*x - 9};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Increasing the number of samples should not be necessary. This might be a bug: it seems that `restrict y to domain` somehow disables math parsing of the `domain` key or has some other odd effect. Commenting out the `restrict y to domain` line _or_ changing `domain={5/6}:4` to `domain=0.833333:4` both resolve the issue without resorting to more samples.

Comment: I agree and have run into the same or similar problems many times with pgfplots.

Comment: @Paul Gessler   I got the line to plot with `domain={5/6+0.01}:{4-0.01}` and two sample points.  I just wanted to ask if others had experienced similar mishaps with `pgfplots`.  At least `JPi` confirms this.

Comment: @Paul Gessler   Why does "commenting  out the `restrict y to domain` line" get the line to be plotted correctly?

Comment: @Adelyn I'm not sure. Like I said, it might be a bug; this behavior is certainly not by design, as far as I can tell.

Comment: JPi and @Adelyn I take back my comment about it possibly being a bug... percusse nailed it with his comment on the question above. Both of my solutions above only work because they happen to eliminate the precision issues.