# A line is not drawn along its domain on `pgfplots`

Tags: pgfplots

I have a line `y = (3/2)*x + 1/2` that is to be graphed over the domain `[-23/9,9]`. The endpoints of the graphed line should be `(-23/9,-10/3)` and `(9,14)`. The line is not drawn along its domain. I have the label for the line placed properly at `(9,14)`, but the right arrowhead of the line is not there.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4.5in, axis equal image, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-6,xmax=9,
    ymin=-2.5556,ymax=14,
    restrict y to domain=-2.5556:14,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x}, ylabel=\textit{y},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex, domain=-6:9] {(-2/3)*x + 8/3};
\addplot[latex-latex, domain=-23/9:9] {(3/2)*x + 1/2};

\addplot [dashed, latex-latex,domain=-2.5556:14] (6,x);
\addplot [dashed, domain=1:6] {2};

\coordinate (A) at (1,2);
\coordinate (B) at (6,19/2);
\coordinate (C) at (6,-4/3);
\coordinate (P) at (6,2);


\coordinate (label_for_k) at (9,-10/3);
\coordinate (label_for_ell) at (9,14);


\draw[fill=green] (label_for_ell) circle (1.5pt);

\end{axis}


\node[anchor={atan(-2/3)+180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(label_for_k) +({atan(-2/3)}:0.15)$){\textit{k}};
\node[anchor={atan(3/2)+180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(label_for_ell) +({atan(3/2)}:0.15)$){$\ell$};


%A "pin" is drawn between the label for A and the point itself.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (A) -- ($(A) +({0.5*(atan(-2/3)+atan(3/2))+180}:1)$);
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(A) +({0.5*(atan(-2/3)+atan(3/2))+180}:1)$){\makebox[0pt][r]{\textit{A}}};

%A "pin" is drawn between the label for B and the point itself.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (B) -- ($(B) +({0.5*(atan(3/2)-90)}:0.75)$);
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(B) +({0.5*(atan(3/2)-90)}:0.75)$){\makebox[0pt][l]{\textit{B}}};

%A "pin" is drawn between the label for C and the point itself.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (C) -- ($(C) +({0.5*(atan(-2/3)+90)+180}:0.75)$);
\node[anchor=north east, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(C) +({0.5*(atan(-2/3)+90)+180}:0.75)$){\makebox[0pt][r]{\textit{C}}};


%A right-angle mark is drawn at A.
\coordinate (U) at ($(A)!3.5mm!-45:(B)$);
\draw ($(A)!(U)!(B)$) -- (U) -- ($(A)!(U)!(C)$);


%A right-angle mark is drawn at P.
\coordinate (V) at ($(P)!3.5mm!-45:(C)$);
\draw ($(A)!(V)!(P)$) -- (V) -- ($(B)!(V)!(P)$);



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adelyn, most of your code is not necessary for showing the problem, it would be a lot nicer if you could trim the example down to the bare necessities needed. The problem is your `restrict y to domain` key.

Comment: The restriction on `y` allows for a maximum value of `14`. The right arrowhead should be at `(9,14)`.

Comment: In theory yes, but if you try you'll see that is obviously not the case. There is such a thing as numerical precision, and in this case the data point for x=9 is cut off. I don't see why you need the `restrict` key in the first place though.

Comment: Are you suggesting to remove `restrict y to domain=-2.5556:14`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: remove your `restrict y to domain=-2.5556:14` setting.

---

Sidenote: Did you intend to have `ymin=-3.333` and `restrict y to domain=-3.333:14`? For x=-23/9 the function value is as you say 10/3, not -23/9.

---

Removing most of your code, one is left with the following example that demonstrates the problem, where the ticks and grid only serve to make it easy to see:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-6,xmax=9,
    ymin=-2.5556,ymax=14,
    xtick={-2.5556,9},
    ytick={-2.5556,14},
    grid,
    restrict y to domain=-2.5556:14
]

  \addplot +[domain=-23/9:9] {(3/2)*x + 1/2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The plot should extend to the top right corner, and below the bottom left, which it does not:

[image]

If you keep removing options from the `axis`, you'll find the it is the `restrict y to domain` key that causes the problem. Combined with the fact that `pgfplots` uses 25 samples by default (which I'm sure I've discussed in some of your previous questions), the plot line ends well away from the top right corner.

I realize that in theory the data point for x=9 should be included, but obviously the calculations and comparisons turn out such that `pgfplots` filters it away. This is likely exactly the same thing as in [A line not plotted using pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325758/a-line-not-plotted-using-pgfplots#comment796378_325758).

Here is an example where the `restrict y to domain` is included to a specific `\addplot` (with blue markers), instead of the `axis` options.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-6,xmax=9,
    ymin=-3.333,ymax=14,
    clip=false,
    only marks,
    xtick={-2.5556,9},
    ytick={-3.333,14},
    grid
]

\addplot[red, domain=-23/9:9, mark=o] {(3/2)*x + 1/2};
\addplot[blue, restrict y to domain=-2.5556:14,domain=-23/9:9, mark=*] {(3/2)*x + 1/2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## So ...

Going back to your original code, I think I would maybe use `samples at` instead of `domain`. It doesn't seem to allow fractions though, so if you prefer to have -23/9 instead of -2.5556, use e.g. `domain=-23/9:9, samples=2` and not `samples at={-2.5556, 9}`.

You do of course still have to remove the `restrict y to domain` line, otherwise you won't get any plots.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4.5in, axis equal image, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-6,xmax=9,
    ymin=-3.333, % changed from 2.5556
    ymax=14,
    %restrict y to domain=-2.5556:14, % you don't want this
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel=\textit{x}, ylabel=\textit{y},
    axis line style={shorten >=-12.5pt, shorten <=-12.5pt},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, xshift=12.5pt, anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)}, yshift=12.5pt, anchor=south west}
]

% used samples=at in the following four \addplots
\addplot[latex-latex, samples at={-6,9}] {(-2/3)*x + 8/3};
\addplot[latex-latex, samples at={-2.5556,9}] {(3/2)*x + 1/2};

\addplot [dashed, latex-latex,samples at={-2.5556,14}] (6,x);
\addplot [dashed, samples at={1,6}] {2};

\coordinate (A) at (1,2);
\coordinate (B) at (6,19/2);
\coordinate (C) at (6,-4/3);
\coordinate (P) at (6,2);


\coordinate (label_for_k) at (9,-10/3);
\coordinate (label_for_ell) at (9,14);


\draw[fill=green] (label_for_ell) circle (1.5pt);

\end{axis}


\node[anchor={atan(-2/3)+180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(label_for_k) +({atan(-2/3)}:0.15)$){\textit{k}};
\node[anchor={atan(3/2)+180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(label_for_ell) +({atan(3/2)}:0.15)$){$\ell$};


%A "pin" is drawn between the label for A and the point itself.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (A) -- ($(A) +({0.5*(atan(-2/3)+atan(3/2))+180}:1)$);
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(A) +({0.5*(atan(-2/3)+atan(3/2))+180}:1)$){\makebox[0pt][r]{\textit{A}}};

%A "pin" is drawn between the label for B and the point itself.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (B) -- ($(B) +({0.5*(atan(3/2)-90)}:0.75)$);
\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(B) +({0.5*(atan(3/2)-90)}:0.75)$){\makebox[0pt][l]{\textit{B}}};

%A "pin" is drawn between the label for C and the point itself.
\draw[draw=gray, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (C) -- ($(C) +({0.5*(atan(-2/3)+90)+180}:0.75)$);
\node[anchor=north east, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at ($(C) +({0.5*(atan(-2/3)+90)+180}:0.75)$){\makebox[0pt][r]{\textit{C}}};


%A right-angle mark is drawn at A.
\coordinate (U) at ($(A)!3.5mm!-45:(B)$);
\draw ($(A)!(U)!(B)$) -- (U) -- ($(A)!(U)!(C)$);


%A right-angle mark is drawn at P.
\coordinate (V) at ($(P)!3.5mm!-45:(C)$);
\draw ($(A)!(V)!(P)$) -- (V) -- ($(B)!(V)!(P)$);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I include `samples=2`, would I get the plot that I want without removing `restrict y to domain=-2.5556:14`?  (Yes, I want the left arrowhead to be at `(-23/9,-10/3)`.)

Comment: @Adelyn The fastest way of finding out is to try. But of course not, the end values would be the same, and they would be filtered away. So you wouldn't get a line at all, because both samples are removed by the filter.

Comment: @Adelyn I would suggest (as I think I have done before), `samples at={-23/9,9}`. And of course remove the `restrict y to domain`.

Comment: I think that I have asked about this in the past - years ago. I would be asking again because it seems that if I specified `samples=2`, `TikZ` would compute the endpoints of the line and draw the line. Do you know what `TikZ` does with `samples=2`?  (I did remove ` restrict y to domain` to get the display that I wanted. Thanks.)

Comment: @Adelyn You will always get the endpoints of the domain, but with `samples=2` you *only* get the endpoints.  In general, with `samples=N, domain=a:b`, `pgfplots` will calculate the function values at `N` equally spaced x-values, starting at `a`, ending at `b`. The `domain` and `samples` determine for which x-values the y-values are calculated, while `restrict y to domain` acts as a filter that removes points where the y-value fall outside the specified range.

Comment: When drawing a line, isn't `samples=2` preferred?

Comment: @Adelyn I don't follow. `samples at` is not the same as `samples`, with `samples at` you provide a list of x-values, not a number of samples, so  `samples at={-6,9}` would give you the same as `samples=2,domain=-6:9`.  If you're talking about first two code samples in my answer, the purpose of those was to explain why you got the output you showed in your question.